# How do you get the 'this' variable defined in a vuejs component unit test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, vue.js, mocha.js, mocha-webpack

I am trying to use mocha-webpack in an npm script to test a vuejs component. I am mocking the vuex store like this in the test:

```
const vm = new Vue({
        template: '<div><test></test></div>',
        store: new Vuex.Store(mockedStore),
        components: {
            'test': TestItems
        }
    }).$mount()
```

I call a method on the component to test such as:

```
vm.$options.components.test.methods.foo()
```

In the component I have code that accesses the store such as:

```
this.$store.commit('bar', data)
```

The problem is when it gets to this point I get this error:

```
'Cannot read property \'commit\' of undefined' undefined undefined
```

I verified that 'this' is undefined in this context. When I run the app, 'this' is defined and has '$store'. How can I make it work in the unit test context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `foo` method of the `test` component without an instance of `test`. Try doing something like this:

```
const vm = new Vue({
  template: '<div><test ref="test"></test></div>',
  store: new Vuex.Store(mockedStore),
  components: {
    'test': TestItems
  }
}).$mount()
```

```
vm.$refs.test.foo()
```

`foo` will be called with `vm.$refs.test` as `this`.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it. I also needed to import vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js' to get the template to compile since the unit test is not in a .vue file.